# type/value mismatch while declaring custom comparator in a class

Tags: c++, stl

I have a problem with the following class. I get error "Tree.cpp:12:56: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template class std::multiset’ // Tree.cpp:12:56: note:   expected a type, got ‘(Tree::compare < )’". I don't understand how I should pass the comparator type in the multiset declaration. Could you help me?

```
#include <set>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Tree
{
    typedef typename std::multiset<Tree<T>*, typename Tree<T>::compare > NodeSet;

private:
    NodeSet children;
    T content;

public:
    struct compare
    {
        bool operator()( const Tree*& t1, const Tree*& t2 ) const
        {
            cout << "Comparing " << t1->GetContent() << " vs " << t2->GetContent() << endl;
            return t1->GetContent() < t2->GetContent();
        }
    };
    Tree& AppendNode( const T& node )
    {
        Tree* t = new Tree( node );
        AttachTree( t );
        return *t;
    }
    void Clear()
    {
        typename NodeSet::iterator it = children.begin();
        while( children.size() != 0 && children.end() != it )
        {

            children.erase( *it );
            delete *it;
            it++;
        }
    }
    Tree( const T& root )
    {
        content = root;
    }
    void AttachTree( Tree* t )
    {
        children.insert( t );
    }
    void Visit( std::deque<T>& exp ) const
    {
        exp.push_back( content );
        typename NodeSet::iterator it = children.begin();
        while( it != children.end() )
        {
            ( *it )->Visit( exp ); it++;
        }
    }
    Tree()
    {}
    Tree( Tree& c )
    {
        c.DeepCopyTo( this );
    }
    T& operator =( const Tree& b )
    {
        b.DeepCopyTo( this );
    }
    ~Tree()
    {
        cout << "in destructor for" << this << endl;
        Clear();
    }
    void DeepCopyTo( Tree* dest ) const
    {
        dest->content = content;
        typename NodeSet::iterator it = children.begin();
        while( it != children.end() )
        {
            Tree* t = new Tree();
            ( *it )->DeepCopyTo( t );
            dest->AttachTree( t );
            it++;
        }
    }
    void Print()
    {
        typename NodeSet::iterator it = children.begin();
        while( it != children.end() )
        {
            cout << *it << ",";
            it++;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Tree<int> tree( 8 );
    tree.AppendNode( 5 );
}
```

Comment: The comparator for a multiset should take two const references; your code requires two *references*. The `const` in your parameters is pinned to the pointer, not the reference. I.e. you're parameters are non-const references to `const Tree *` objects. That's wrong. It should be *at least* `Tree * const&`

Comment: @WhozCraig compiler still complains about "no type named ‘compare’ in ‘class Tree<int>’"

Comment: [Move the comparator above the typedef.](http://ideone.com/58Ml52)

Comment: @WhozCraig yessss.... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change this line to

```
typedef 
    typename std::multiset<Tree*, typename Tree::compare > 
    NodeSet;
```

Note that `compare` is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name), so you need to use `typename`.

Also, you should consider moving the struct `compare` above this line, as this line references it.

Two more things to notice.

You might want to change `compare` to

```
struct compare {
    bool operator()(const Tree* t1, const Tree* t2) const {
    cout << "Comparing " <<t1->GetContent() <<" vs "<<t2->GetContent()<<endl;                                                                                        
        return t1->GetContent() < t2->GetContent();
    }   
};
```

unfortunately, `GetContent` doesn't seem defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Surferonthefall It doesn't compile by me either, but the error moves on to a further line. Note also that your example is incomplete (you omitted the `#include`s), so it's not possible to completely address your errors.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to write just `Tree`, as it's an _injected-class-name_ or whatever - but there are occasions that doesn't work for some reason

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Thanks for the comment. I will read up on that.

Comment: updated code.. It seems to me that the problem is still in the multiset line!

Comment: "Tree.cpp:9:65: error: no type named ‘compare’ in ‘class Tree<int>’"!

Comment: @Surferonthefall That is still not the full code, I believe.

Comment: The reason why you changed compare... because copying (instead of dealing with references) pointers is just as efficient.. isn't it?

Comment: Moreover: there's a way to avoid writing all the time typename in front of NodeSet? thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: @Surferonthefall If you find yourself repeating something often, like `typename NodeSet::iterator`, you can use `typedef typename NodeSet::iterator nodeset_iterator_t`.

Comment: Or `using nodeset_iterator_t = NodeSet::iterator;`